# Almost sure convergence of the continuous uniform distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I have recently been working through problems on the convergence of random variables. In the following exercise, I believe I have shown that the following random variable does not converge almost surely. However, the question asks me to show that it does. I am unsure about what the mistake is in my process and would be grateful for any help.

> Consider the random variable $X$ following the continuous uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$, and define the sequence of random variables $Y_n= \frac{X}{n}$. Show that $Y_n$ converges almost surely.

I have been able to show that $Y_n$ converges in distribution and converges in probability to $Y=0$ so far.

My attempt to show almost sure convergence was to show the following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|Y_n-0| \ge\epsilon) < \infty$$

I believe that this should be sufficient to prove almost sure convergence.

I have computed the CDF of $Y_n$ as $F_{Y_n}(y)= \frac{ny+1}{2}$ for $y \in (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$

Therefore, if I have computed this correctly, the sum should simplify (for $\epsilon \in (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$), we should have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \epsilon $$

However, this appears to diverge, as if we try to bound the sum by replacing $\epsilon$ with $\frac{1}{n}$, then we end up with the infinite sum of a constant - which clearly diverges rather than converges (as we need to show).

I would be grateful for any help resolving my problem.

Comment: For any $\omega \in \Omega$, we have $|Y_n(\omega)|= |X(\omega)|/n\leq 1/n\to 0$. Therefore $Y_n\to 0$ surely (and a.s.).

Comment: @Snoop Thanks. That makes sense. What went wrong with my methodology? I believe that showing that the sum converges should also be a valid method by the first Borel Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: The sum converging would imply a.s. convergence of $Y_n$, but a.s. convergence of $Y_n$ does not imply the sum converges, so you can't conclude anything from the sum diverging.

Comment: Also, the $\varepsilon$ in your sum is a constant and is the same for every term in the sum.  That means, for example, that if $\varepsilon > \frac 1n$ then every term in your sum after the first $n$ is $0$, and hence the sum converges.  When you say $\varepsilon \in (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$, it seems like you want that to hold for all $n$, which would imply $\varepsilon = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall weaken the assumptions and prove $P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})=0$ with the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Let $|X|\leq M$ a.s., that is $P(|X|\leq M)=1$. Then $P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})=0$. To see this:
$$P(|Y_n|> \varepsilon)=P(|X|> n\varepsilon)=1-P(-n\varepsilon \leq X\leq n\varepsilon)$$
For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_\varepsilon$ s.t. $\forall n > N_\varepsilon$, $P(-n\varepsilon \leq X\leq n\varepsilon)=1$. Indeed, just choose $N_\varepsilon=M/\varepsilon$. Thus $\sum_{n}P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon)=\sum_{n\leq N_\varepsilon}P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon)<\infty$. By Borel-Cantelli, $P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})=0$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be be easier to say $|Y_n|>\varepsilon$ is only possible if $\frac1n \ge \varepsilon$ i.e.  if $n\le \frac1\varepsilon$, so it cannot happen more than $\frac1\varepsilon$ times (which is finite) and certainly cannot happen infinitely often for any $\varepsilon>0$ ?

Comment: @Henry I think OP wanted an answer with the Borel-Cantelli lemma, as per the comments

Comment: That would just be an extra step:  $\sum P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon) \le \frac1\varepsilon \lt \infty$